# write htest to excel or an image

Tags: r, export, jpeg

I have a list

`thelist`

```
$Delägare.Totalt

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa
t = -4.2515, df = 4525.773, p-value = 0.00002166
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -194.58860  -71.76597
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       207.2441        340.4214 


$Delägare.AndelKvinnor

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa
t = -3.358, df = 5204.392, p-value = 0.0007907
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.3451054 -0.8790346
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       35.09412        37.20619 

class(thelist)
[1] "list"

class(thelist[[1]])
[1] "htest"
```

I would like to export it nicely to excel or a jpg file. Any suggestions?

Best Regards!

```
dput(thelist)
structure(list(Delägare.Totalt = structure(list(statistic = structure(-4.25153766803811, .Names = "t"), 
    parameter = structure(4525.77251107907, .Names = "df"), p.value = 0.0000216586994081083, 
    conf.int = structure(c(-194.588596176246, -71.7659721316704
    ), conf.level = 0.95), estimate = structure(c(207.244090610637, 
    340.421374764595), .Names = c("mean in group 0", "mean in group 1"
    )), null.value = structure(0, .Names = "difference in means"), 
    alternative = "two.sided", method = "Welch Two Sample t-test", 
    data.name = "x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa"), .Names = c("statistic", 
"parameter", "p.value", "conf.int", "estimate", "null.value", 
"alternative", "method", "data.name"), class = "htest"), Delägare.AndelKvinnor = structure(list(
    statistic = structure(-3.35800910076486, .Names = "t"), parameter = structure(5204.39192454832, .Names = "df"), 
    p.value = 0.000790696715995022, conf.int = structure(c(-3.34510541135959, 
    -0.879034608967678), conf.level = 0.95), estimate = structure(c(35.0941200840133, 
    37.2061900941769), .Names = c("mean in group 0", "mean in group 1"
    )), null.value = structure(0, .Names = "difference in means"), 
    alternative = "two.sided", method = "Welch Two Sample t-test", 
    data.name = "x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa"), .Names = c("statistic", 
"parameter", "p.value", "conf.int", "estimate", "null.value", 
"alternative", "method", "data.name"), class = "htest")), .Names = c("Delägare.Totalt", 
"Delägare.AndelKvinnor"))
```

Comment: Try `gplots::textplot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
> sapply(thelist, unlist)
                               Delägare.Totalt                   Delägare.AndelKvinnor            
statistic.t                    "-4.25153766803811"               "-3.35800910076486"              
parameter.df                   "4525.77251107907"                "5204.39192454832"               
p.value                        "2.16586994081083e-05"            "0.000790696715995022"           
conf.int1                      "-194.588596176246"               "-3.34510541135959"              
conf.int2                      "-71.7659721316704"               "-0.879034608967678"             
estimate.mean in group 0       "207.244090610637"                "35.0941200840133"               
estimate.mean in group 1       "340.421374764595"                "37.2061900941769"               
null.value.difference in means "0"                               "0"                              
alternative                    "two.sided"                       "two.sided"                      
method                         "Welch Two Sample t-test"         "Welch Two Sample t-test"        
data.name                      "x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa" "x by datattest$Uttaxeringskassa"
```

and then save ist via `write.table`.

**Update**

to save to .jpeg you could use gridExtra:::grid.table:

```
df <- sapply(thelist, unlist)
require(gridExtra)
jpeg("output.jpg")
grid.table(df)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know that way, but I would like to save `thelist` as an image! :)